# OpenGLES - Create objects at runtime

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm new to OpenGL and started with the small tutorial from dev.android.com. The sample code includes this `Square` class for a square geometry. The object will be created in the `onSurfaceCreated()` method and drawn every frame using `onDrawFrame()`. Here is the example code of the `Square` (constructor and draw-method):

```
   public Square() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(squareCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
    int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShaderCode);

    int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
            GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables
}


public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    MyGLRenderer.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Draw the square
    GLES20.glDrawElements(
            GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
```

My question is now: how can I create the object not at `onSurfaceCreated()` but after a touch event?

I tried to define a `Square` variable but not initialize it at `onSurfaceCreated()`, then check if the object is null before drawing it. After the touch I called:

```
mSquare = new Square();
```

I know it's not a good way of implementing this, but I just wanted to try if it works. I would have created a list of drawable elements and run through it in the `onDrawFrame()` method, calling every `draw()` from the list objects. But since this method causes the program to crash, I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only make calls to OpenGL within an OpenGL context.

There are 3 methods in which this context exists:

1) `onSurfaceCreated` - when context is created/recreated - you should load resources here

2) `onSurfaceChanged` - after creation and on a surface resize - you should assign size-dependent variables here

3) `onDrawFrame` - here rendering is executed - here you should execute all drawing commands

If you try to execute OpenGL calls outside of the context, most likely the code will fail to execute correctly.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer

so would it be a good solution to change for example a boolean with the touch event, so that the onDrawFrame method creates the object?

Comment: Best if you pre-load all objects that you'll use before onDrawFrame. In onTouchEvent you might change some parameters(for example which objects to display and where) and in onDrawFrame you use this parameters for rendering

Answer (score 0):

Android and GL contexts are different and they run on different(manages) threads in their own way
so if you want to create a square on the touch you've to create object, you have to do it in GLcontext like this

1. http://pastebin.com/zAav7jpu
2. Initialize your object in touch/or where you want to do

   public static isAddedBody = false; //declare globally in touch_class
   public void touch(int.. whateva){
     mSquare = new Square();
     isAddedBody = true;

   }

in render()/or draw() loop

```
if (touch_class.isAddedBody){
  mSquare.createBody();
  touch_class.isAdded = false;
}
```